# writing to a file with buffer and nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

sample text file that I'm reading:

**INPUT**:

```
carmaker blah1;

option -car {ford}

option -car {bmw}
    
option -features {lane_detection}

option -features {speed_control}
    
option -color {blue}

option -color {black}

option -color {red}

option -color {silver}
    
endofcarmeker
    
carmaker blah2;

option -car {Audi}

option -car {Cheverolet}
  
option -features {lane_detection}

option -features {speed_control}
    
option -color {blue}

option -color {black}

option -color {red}
    
endofcarmaker
   
carmaker blah3;

option -car {Volkswagen}

option -car {Cheverolet}
    
option -features {lane_detection}

option -features {speed_control}
  
option -color {blue}

option -color {black}

option -color {red}

endofcarmaker
```

output expected in a txt file:

```
-blah1:
  CAR:
    -FORD
    -BMW
  FEATURES:
    - lane_detection
    - speed_control
  COLOR:
    - blue
    -  black
    -  red
    - silver

-blah2:
  CAR:
    -Audi
    -cheverolet
  FEATURES:
    - lane_detection
    - speed_control
  COLOR:
    - blue
    -  black
    -  red

-blah3:
  CAR:
    -volkswagen
    -cheverolet
  FEATURES:
    - lane_detection
    - speed_control
  COLOR:
    - blue
    -  black
    -  red
```

So,this is the code I've tried so far, where I'm unable to convert the nested loops: As I'm learning, I'd want to do this with while, for loops and functions.

```
import sys
import re
file1= open(sys.argv[1], "r")
out1= open(sys.argv[2], "w+")
file  = file1.readlines()
strip_line2 = []
Lib = []
for line in file: # I tried to buffer this output as Lib = [] ; but when i do print the output at the bottom of the code, this fails as in it only prints the last line or the blah3*
   if line.startswith('carmaker'):
      line= line[line.find(' ')+1 : line.find(';')]
      out1.write('- '+line+':'+'\n')
 
incl = open('feature.txt', "r+")
for rline2 in file:
    if  re.search('-features', rline2):# in line:
     strip_line2 = rline2[rline2.find('{')+1 : rline2.find('}')]
     incl.write(strip_line2+'\n')


blah =open('blah.txt', "w")
for f in out1:
 print(f, file=blah)
  for b in incl:
   print(b, file=blah)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow. It would help us a lot to answer your question if you could trim it down into a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, there seems to be a lot of extra code surrounding where the actual error lies.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a yaml file. Use the `yaml` module.

**Demo**:

```
import yaml

result = {}
key = None
with open(filename) as infile:        
    while True:
        try:
            line = next(infile).strip()  
        except:
            break #END OF File
        if line:
            if line == 'endofcarmaker':
                pass
            else:
                if line.startswith("carmaker"):
                    key = line.split()[1].strip(";")
                else:
                    _, head, value = line.split()
                    result.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault(head, []).append(value.strip("{}"))
                
with open(yfilename, 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(result, f)
```

**Output:**

```
blah1:
  -car:
  - ford
  - bmw
  -color:
  - blue
  - black
  - red
  - silver
  -features:
  - lane_detection
  - speed_control
blah2:
  -car:
  - Audi
  - Cheverolet
  -color:
  - blue
  - black
  - red
  -features:
  - lane_detection
  - speed_control
blah3:
  -car:
  - Volkswagen
  - Cheverolet
  -color:
  - blue
  - black
  - red
  -features:
  - lane_detection
  - speed_control
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution,

```
import re

results = {}

# extract values between carmaker & endofcarmaker
for _, x in re.findall("(carmaker(.*?)endofcarmaker)", text,
                       re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
    root_key = ""
    for l in x.splitlines():
        if not l.strip():
            continue

        # carmaker blah1; (identify start value & use as rootkey)
        if l.endswith(";"):
            root_key = l.strip().replace(";", "")
            results[root_key] = {}
        else:
            # option -car {ford} (extract {car} & {ford})
            k, v = re.search("option -(\w+) {(\w+)}", l).groups()
            # create key {car} for root node (blah1)
            if not results[root_key].get(k):
                results[root_key][k] = []

            # append values for blah > car > [ford...]
            results[root_key][k].append(v)
```

---

```
# pip install PyYAML
import yaml

with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(results, outfile)
```

---

```
/data.yml

blah1:
  car:
  - ford
  - bmw
  color:
  - blue
  - black
  - red
  - silver
  features:
  - lane_detection
  - speed_control
blah2:
  car:
  - Audi
  - Cheverolet

...
```